# PHPMailer didn't send email message

Tags: phpmailer

I try to send email with PHPMailer but getting error.I use port 465 and 587 both are getting error also in SSL and TLS. Error like bellow

2016-06-09 18:55:06 Could not instantiate mail function. Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: Could not instantiate mail function.

How can i solve this and can send email message.

```
        $mail = new PHPMailer;

        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = 'nuralam862@gmail.com';
        $mail->Password = '********';
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail->Port = 587;   

        $mail->From = 'nuralam862@gmail.com';
        $mail->FromName = 'nuralam';
        $mail->addAddress('nuralam862@gmail.com', 'nuralam');

        $mail->addReplyTo('nuralam862@gmail.com', 'nuralam');

        $mail->WordWrap = 50;
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; 
        $mail->Subject = 'Using PHPMailer';
        $mail->Body    = 'Hi Iam using PHPMailer library to sent SMTP mail from localhost';

        if(!$mail->send()) {
           echo 'Message could not be sent.';
           echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
           exit;
        }
        echo 'Message has been sent';
```

Comment: I had similar problems in the past on my test system due to not having a mail server running. Can you send email via the standard php function?

Comment: what is the function.

Comment: Sorry, this one: http://php.net/manual/de/function.mail.php

Comment: how can i make a  mail server running

Comment: This depends on your setup. I ended up using a google email address and not running my own server. You can google search a tutorial for a tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

First up, you're using an old version of PHPMailer and you need to [read the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting). [Get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Because you're using SMTP directly, you don't need a local mail server.

If you increase SMTP debug output you'll be able to see what responses you're getting from the server, which is very likely to be an authentication problem, as described in the troubleshooting guide.

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
```

Comment: I again download phpmailer from your link but still it's not work.Pls help me.